# Can I create a bullet system by auto generated instances of a class? (PYGAME)

Tags: python, function, oop, pygame, sprite

I am creating a target shooter game where the player clicks their mouse and a bullet flies towards it. I have started using 'pygame.sprite' to make things easier. I currently have managed to load targets and a background, and make the targets move. Now I want to make the bullet function. Ideally I want to use the 'pygame.sprite' commands again so that I can use the pre-made collision detection system. The issue is I obviously can't sit here and instantiate hundreds of bullets which will spawn upon click. I have read threads about auto-instantiation but none of them are similar to my problem where I need it incorporated into pygame. All bullets will share the same properties except 'self.rect.x/y' but I can handle that later. Basically, is there a way I can make it so that an instance can be auto created during execution? Note that 'refresh_window()' is to contain all drawing commands.

```
#Using pygame.sprite to make a class for the bullet sprites.
bullet_img = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, width, height):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, bullet_sprites)
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image = bullet_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (400,400)

bullet_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Creating a function which will deal with redrawing all sprites and updating the screen.
def refresh_window():
  window.blit(bgr, (0,0))
  player_sprites.draw(window)
  target_sprites.draw(window)
  bullet_sprites.draw(window)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new `Bullet` on every mouse click.  Then add it to your group.  Maybe you just left that part out of the question's code, but sprites that move should define an `update()` function to move themselves (or whatever else it is that they do).

```
bullet_img = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')

class Bullet( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y, speed=1.5 ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        global bullet_img
        self.image       = bullet_img
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( from_x, from_y )
        self.speed       = speed

        # Calculate how far we should move in X and Y each update.
        # Basically this is just a pair of numbers that get added
        # to the co-ordinate each update to move the bullet towards
        # its destination.
        from_point  = pygame.math.Vector2( ( from_x, from_y ) )
        to_point    = pygame.math.Vector2( ( to_x, to_y ) )
        distance    = from_point.distance_to( to_point )     # 2D line length
        self.dir_x  = ( to_x - from_x ) / distance           # normalised direction in x
        self.dir_y  = ( to_y - from_y ) / distance           # normalised direction in y
        # Store the position as a float for slow-speed and small angles
        # Otherwise sub-pixel updates can be lost
        self.position = ( float( from_x ), float( from_y ) )

    def update( self ):
        # How far do we move this update?
        # TODO: maybe change to use millisecond timings instead of frame-speed
        x_movement = self.speed * self.dir_x
        y_movement = self.speed * self.dir_y
        self.position[0] += x_movement
        self.position[1] += y_movement
        # convert back to integer co-ordinates for the rect
        self.rect.center = ( int( self.position[0] ), int( self.position[1] ) )
        ### TODO: when ( offscreen ): self.kill()
```

In your main loop, whenever the player fires a new bullet, create an object, and add it to the sprite group.

```
# ...

bullet_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# ...

### MAIN Loop
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
             # Bullet from TURRET in the direction of the click
            start_x = WINDOW_WIDTH//2
            start_y = int( WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.9 )  # where is this?
            end_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            to_x    = end_pos[0]
            to_y    = end_pos[1]
            # Create a new Bullet every mouse click!
            bullet_sprites.add( Bullet( start_x, start_y, to_x, to_y ) )
```

Also in your main loop, don't forget to call

```
bullet_sprites.update()
```

Which calls the `update()` function of every sprite in the group.  This will move the bullets along their trajectory.